# Video sources are broken | Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I got the source for Ad Video, but I found out some source (not all) are broken. The broken sources show a "gone" text on my browser and I am sure the video is still alive in my ad account.

What was the cause of the problem and How to solve it?

[facebook graph api explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/2153215214914858/?method=GET&path=523693511726242%3Ffields%3Did%2Csource&version=v8.0)

```
{
  "id": "523693511726242",
  "source": "https://video.ftpe7-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.24130-2/10000000_601583997150274_748629584611160856_n.mp4?_nc_cat=107&_nc_sid=985c63&efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6Im9lcF9oZCJ9&_nc_ohc=68WEvQXqpIIAX94To8x&_nc_ht=video.ftpe7-4.fna&oh=f83d0101e60ab8fba47a0aeadb3a4101&oe=5F91DF2C"
}
```

Comment: Is this a URL you requested recently, or did you do that a while ago and store it? These CDN URLs aren’t supposed to be valid forever.

Comment: yes, the url is recent I requested. I know the urls are temporary.

Comment: Currently works fine for a page of mine, so no idea what’s wrong here. The page is fully public, and the video has no feed/targetting restrictions?

Comment: Yes, the page is public. But how to check the feed/targetting restrictions for a video?